# Blocked a frame with origin "" from accessing a frame with origin "https://s-static.ak.facebook.com"

Tags: facebook

Before, the code did not have this error, but there are three days I am getting this error on my page.

```
Blocked a frame with origin "myhomepage in https" from accessing a frame with origin "https://s-static.ak.facebook.com". The frame being accessed set "document.domain" to "facebook.com", but the frame requesting access did not. Both must set "document.domain" to the same value to allow access.
```

What might be happening?
thank you and sorry for my bad english